# Problem with loop in python - Multiple entries of same data

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop, file-handling

I am appending a .csv file with python. The data is scraped from the web. I am through with almost everything related to scraping.

The problem is coming when I am trying to append the file. It enters multiple >100s of entries of same data. So **I am sure there is a problem with the loop/ for or if statements that i am not able to identify and solve.**

The condition checks for similarity in data scraped from web and already existing data in file.
If data doesn't match then program writes a new row, else it breaks or continues.

Note: csvFileArray is an array which checks data from existing file.txt. for example `print(csvFileArray[0])` gives:

```
{'Date': '19/05/21', 'Time': '14:51:00', 'Status': 'Waitlisted', 'School': 'MIT Sloan', 'Details': 'GPA: 3.4 Round: Round 2 | Texas'}
```

Below is the code that has a problem.

```
file = open('file.csv', 'a')
writer = csv.writer(file) 

#loop for page numbers
for page in range(15, 17):
    
    print("Getting page {}..".format(page))
    
    params["paged"] = page
    data = requests.post(url, data=params).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data["markup"], "html.parser")
    
    for entry in soup.select(".livewire-entry"):
        
        datime = entry.select_one(".adate")
        status = entry.select_one(".status")
        name = status.find_next("strong")
        details = entry.select_one(".lw-details")

        datime = datime.get_text(strip=True)
        datime = datetime.datetime.strptime(datime, '%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p')
        time = datime.time() #returns time
        date = datime.date() #returns date
        
        for firstentry in csvFileArray:
            condition = (((firstentry['Date']) == date) and ((firstentry['Time']) == time)
                        and ((firstentry['Status']) == (status.get_text(strip=True))) and ((firstentry['School']) == (name.get_text(strip=True)))
                        and ((firstentry['Details']) == details.get_text(strip=True)))
    
            
            if condition:
                continue
                        
            else:
                writer.writerow([date, time, status.get_text(strip=True), name.get_text(strip=True),details.get_text(strip=True)])       
                #print('ok')
        
            
    print("-" * 80) 

file.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I can't do much debugging with what you've posted. What I can do is suggest that you use `set` to ensure uniqueness instead of iterating over each element in `csvFileArray` for each new `entry`, for each new `page`. Now, `dict` isn't hashable, you'll need to do some transformation, but it will make the code clearer and more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to write the line only if the condition is true for ALL of the `csvFileArray` entries.  Right now, you're writing it for EVERY `csvFileArray` that doesn't match.

```
    for entry in soup.select(".livewire-entry"):
        
        datime = entry.select_one(".adate")
        status = entry.select_one(".status")
        name = status.find_next("strong")
        details = entry.select_one(".lw-details")

        datime = datime.get_text(strip=True)
        datime = datetime.datetime.strptime(datime, '%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p')
        time = datime.time() #returns time
        date = datime.date() #returns date

        should_write = True        
        for firstentry in csvFileArray:
            if (((firstentry['Date']) == date) and ((firstentry['Time']) == time)
                        and ((firstentry['Status']) == (status.get_text(strip=True))) and ((firstentry['School']) == (name.get_text(strip=True)))
                        and ((firstentry['Details']) == details.get_text(strip=True))):
                should_write = False
                break
                        
        if should_write:
            writer.writerow([date, time, status.get_text(strip=True), name.get_text(strip=True),details.get_text(strip=True)])       
            #print('ok')
```

You could also use a list comprehension for this, but because your condition is large, that gets hard to read:

```
        if not any(
            (((firstentry['Date']) == date) and ((firstentry['Time']) == time)
                    and ((firstentry['Status']) == (status.get_text(strip=True))) and ((firstentry['School']) == (name.get_text(strip=True)))
                    and ((firstentry['Details']) == details.get_text(strip=True)))
            for firstentry in csvFileArray):
            writer.writerow([date, time, status.get_text(strip=True), name.get_text(strip=True),details.get_text(strip=True)])       
            #print('ok')
```

Comment: Thanks, yes i want to write for every csvfile array that doesnt match. And I am getting mulitple hundreds same value.